# Postgres DB not starting in Docker - Mac

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, postgresql-9.1

I already using Postgres DB in my development and at the last time when I'm push my Spring Micro-services the Postgres DB is not starting, following is the docker output from kitematic

```
The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
2017-10-17T08:37:47.562145630Z 
Data page checksums are disabled.
2017-10-17T08:37:47.562162938Z 
fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
initdb: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog": No space left on device
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

Any one have a idea on this? I couldn't find a solution

Comment: `No space left on device` is hint that your space is over... extentd the disk?..

Answer (score 6):

Hi if you have good amount of space in your machine ,then this problem is because of dangling images and dangling volume remove those using
`docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -f dangling=true -q)` or `docker volume prune` ,for images
`docker rmi $(docker images -f dangling=true -q)`

you can also do `docker system prune` to clean the docker completely

if you still face this problem the only way to do is reset the docker complete just like a new one